# HashSet in unit tests

Tags: java, junit, hashset

I have a bunch of methods returning HashSet. I would like my unit test to check the state of these objects i.e confirm that `someObject.getName() == "foobar"`.

However the hashset iterator order is not guaranteed so my unit tests fail some times. How do I write unit tests for something like this?

Eg:

```
@Test
    public void testRowsToBeRead(){
        HashSet<SomeObject> rows = new SomeObject().read();
        assertEquals(19, rows.size());

        for(SomeObject r:rows){
            //How do I confirm contents?
        }
    }
```

I think I might have accepted an answer too soon.

The problem I now have is that I have implemented the equals method, which checks only for 2 fields in the object per design (it is mimicking a DB table).
However in my unit test, I want to check for all fields like description etc which is not in my equals. So if 2 of fields get swapped and these fields are not in my equals implementation, then the unit test gives a false positive.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My approach:

```
public void testRowsToBeRead(){
    HashSet<SomeObject> expectedRows = new HasSet<SomeObject();
    expectedRows.add(new SomeObject("abc"));
    expectedRows.add(new SomeObject("def"));

    HashSet<SomeObject> rows = new SomeObject().read();

    // alternative 1
    assertEquals(19, rows.size());

    for(SomeObject r:rows){
        if (!expectedRows.contains(r)) {
            // test failed
        }
    }

    // alternative 2
    assertTrue(expectedRows.equals(rows));
}
```

To rely on this test you may need other unit tests confirming that `SomeObject`'s `equals`  and `hashCode` methods work as they should be...

**EDIT based on one of your comments**

If you want to check for fields not part of the `equals` contract, you have to iterate through the set:

```
public void testRowsToBeRead(){
    HashSet<SomeObject> expectedRows = new HasSet<SomeObject();
    expectedRows.add(new SomeObject("a", "a1"));
    expectedRows.add(new SomeObject("b", "b1"));

    HashSet<SomeObject> rows = new SomeObject().read();

    for(SomeObject r : rows) {
        SomeObject expected = expectedRows.get(r); // equals and hashCode must still match

        if (expected == null) {
            // failed
        }

        if (!expected.getField1().equals(r.getField1()) && !expected.getField2().equals(r.getField2())) {
            // failed
        }
    }
}
```

In the above example `SomeObject`'s `equals` may look like this, it only checks for `field1`:

```
@Override
public boolean equals(Object other) {
    return this.getField1().equals( ((SomeObject) other).getField1() );
}
```

No question, depending on your concrete use case this may become more complex. Hope this helps...

Comment: `equals` and `hashCode` must be implemented right to use this approach (and use HashSet).

Comment: I do  have the equals and hashcode unit tests already, so I think this gives me exactly what I am looking for.

Comment: Won't HashSet#equals just do the same? I.e., `if (!expcectedRows.equals(rows)) { /* fail */ }`

Comment: @Arturs Licis: +1, according to JavaDOc you're right, it should behave the same... saved four lines of code :-)

Comment: The problem I now have is that I have implemented the equals method, which checks only for 2 fields in the object per design (it is mimicking a DB table). However in my unit test, I want to check for all fields like description etc which is not in my equals. So if 2 of fields get swapped and these fields are not in my equals implementation, then the unit test gives a false positive.

Comment: @home Thank you.  This is exactly what I ended up doing. Saw your answer today. My unit tests are quite verbose at this point, but it solves the problem.

Answer (score 5):

You can use `LinkedHashSet` which guarantee order.

Comment: Thanks. This needs me to change the actual method. I might end up doing that some time in the future, but right now I am just looking to get my unit test going.

Comment: `LinkedHashSet` will guarantee **insertion** order, if you need **sorting** order, use `TreeSet`, but take note that they are both not thread-safe.

Answer (score 2):

Try to use assertThat:

```
Assert.assertThat(r.getName(), AnyOf.anyOf(Is.is("foobar1"), Is.is("foobar2"), ...));
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use Assert.assertEquals() on pretty much any collection with TestNG and probably JUnit as well.

If you want to roll this yourself, remove all the elements of the actual set from the expected set and assert that the expected set's size is zero when you're done.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend use `HashSet.equals(Object)`.

JavaDoc says:

*This implementation first checks if the specified object is this set; if so it returns true.  Then, it checks if the specified object is a set whose size is identical to the size of this set; if not, it returns false.  If so, it returns containsAll((Collection) o).*

So I think "home"'s "alternative 2" is enough.

plus: Although HashSet doesn't guarantee the order, equaled HashSets are in same order and size.